# Intel SGX training lab: cannot compile examples (sgx_tstdcxx.lib missing)

Tags: sgx

I've installed the latest version of Intel SGX SDK and PSW on Windows 10 (build 18362.356). I downloaded the [Intel SGX Lab Bundle](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/the-intel-sgx-web-based-training-lab-bundle) and opened the first solution (Lab 1.1 Feature Detection). When I compile any project in that solution, the linker complains, stating that:

> cannot open input file 'sgx_tstdcxx.lib'

After reviewing the content of the folder */bin* of SGX SDK, the file is indeed missing (it seems there is only a file with a similar name: *sgx_tstdc.lib*). Does anyone know how to properly compile the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libsgx_tstdc++ has been deprecated. Replace it by libsgx_tcxx.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this library is no longer necessary with the more recent versions of the SGX SDK? I ran into this issue when running some of the examples linked to from https://sgx101.gitbook.io

In my case, when building the PasswordWallet example, the following link error was displayed:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsgx_tstdcxx
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:199: recipe for target 'enclave.so' failed
```

I dropped the `-lsgx_tstdcxx` from the Makefile (
https://github.com/sangfansh/SGX101_sample_code/blob/master/PasswordWallet/Makefile#L124) and the example now compiles and runs successfully.